# Адрес начала строки в памяти после повторного использования оператора new

Tags: c++

Допустим, есть код:

```
сhar* s = “Hello”;
char* str = new char[strlen(s) + 1];
strcpy(str,s);
char* p_str = str;   //дополнительный указатель на эту строку
…
//далее есть необходимость сделать так
сhar* t = “world”;
delete [] str;
str = new char[strlen(t) + 1];
strcpy(str,t);
```

Правильно ли предположить, что после второго использования оператора new адрес начала строки str может уже отличаться (но не обязательно) от первоначального значения адреса str? Т.е. может так получится, что дополнительный указатель p_str будет «смотреть» уже не туда?

Comment: Конечно, адрес не обязан быть тем же. Даже если вы в промежутке ничего не делали.

Comment: Если у вас один поток и ничего не делали в промежутке - вероятно да. Библиотека сокета может дополнительный поток создавать. Некоторые другие библиотеки могут тихо дополнительный поток создавать в вашем процессе.

Comment: современные компиляторы используют разнообразные ASan (способы проверки адресов и валидности указателей) и они будут стараться избегать переиспользовать один и тот же адрес.  `//далее есть необходимость сделать так
сhar* t = “world”;` - нормальный компилятор должен был бы поругать на этом месте.

Comment: Первые 4 строки на strdup похожи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно предположить, что после вызова `delete[]` значение указателя `p_str` становится невалидным, так как время жизни объекта, на который тот указывал, закончилось. При этом вернет ли повторный вызов оператора `new` то же самое значение или другое - совсем не важно. Совпадения значения невалидного указателя с адресом живого объекта подходящего типа в С++ не делает указатель снова валидным. Для редких сценариев, когда такая ситуация используется (например повторные placement new), существует специальная "оживляющая" операция [`::std::launder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder).